# Trying to get the output to show in a horizontal line instead of a new line for each character

Tags: python

I tried using end="", but it doesn't work either way, so I want to know what the correct way to do it is.

```
thislist = ["T", "G", "C", "A"]

for i in range(40):
  print(random.choice(thislist))
  print(i, end="")
```

Comment: Why do you have an `end=""` on only one of your `print` statements? Thats the problem.  Put an `end=""` on the other one as well.

Answer (score 1):

The first `print` call is forcing the newline.

Any print function by default prints a newline character at the end of the string.
The following modification

```
thislist = ["T", "G", "C", "A"]

for i in range(40):
  print(random.choice(thislist), end="")
  print(i, end="")
```

produces output like
`T0G1A2T3C4A5...`

but you probably WANT to omit the `print(i, end="")` like so

```
thislist = ["T", "G", "C", "A"]

for i in range(40):
  print(random.choice(thislist), end="")
```

Answer (score 0):

Hello and thanks for asking!
What about this:

```py
import random
thislist = ["T", "G", "C", "A"]

for i in range(40):
  print(random.choice(thislist),end="")
  print(i, end=" ")
```

it produces:
`A0 C1 C2 G3 G4 C5 T6 G7 G8 T9 C10 C11 G12 A13 G14 A15 T16 T17 T18 C19 A20 T21 T22 T23 C24 C25 A26 A27 G28 A29 G30 T31 C32 G33 A34 A35 C36 T37 G38 T39`

the `end` parameter of `print` by default is `\n`. You have to replace it in both prints so that the first print statement doesnt break between the number and the char.

Another option would be to put both values in one print statement:

```py
...
for i in range(40):
  print(f"{random.choice(thislist)}{i}",end=" ")
```

Comment: is there a way to get only the values and not the string numbers

Comment: wait nevermind i just fixed it. Thanks for your help btw